# Window is completely white in LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have a main package like so:

```java
// Imports and package stuff

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialisation code

        long window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello World", 0, 0);

        // Initialisation code

        glfwShowWindow(window);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GL.createCapabilities();
        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
                glVertex2f(0.5f, 0.5f);
                glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.5f);
                glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);
                glVertex2f(-0.5f, 0.5f);
            glEnd();
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }

        glfwTerminate();
    }
}
```

(The `//` comments show omitted code).

I expect the output "window" to be a black window with a red rectangle in the middle, but what I'm getting is a window with a white background.

At first, I suspected it was the `glClearColor` line messing up (because it sets the default colour to be cleared, and maybe that was white). I tried editing the `glClearColor` line (I fiddled around with the alpha values, as well as the RGB), but they all resulted in the same white background.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

So, I tried running your code and I was getting a NullPointerException on

```
glfwShowWindow(window);
```

So, try putting

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    System.err.println("GLFW Failed to initialize!");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

before you create your window.  This worked for me.  Hope this helped!

Comment: That's in the initialisation code (in the commented bits). I left it out because it wasn't part of what the problem was.

Comment: To clarify, it's not in the snippet above, but it's in my actual code. That piece of code is not part of my problem.

Comment: By removing the initialization, you make it harder for other people to reproduce your problem. Try hard to make your snippet SSCCE: http://sscce.org/